# Cnn with numpy, add another Layer

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I discovered this CNN with numpy through a tutorial and wanted to expand it. Unfortunately, I can't manage to implement the updates for conv1 (i.e. the determination of conv2_delta. Can anyone help me?

Tutorial Link: https://medium.com/@PAdhokshaja/simple-cnn-using-part-v-putting-it-all-together-b4210cd14487

```
    for i in range(batches):
        start = i*batch_size
        end = min(start+batch_size,data_array.shape[0]-1)
        X_batch = data_array_train[start:end, :, :, :]
       # print(len(X_batch))
        y_batch = one_hot_encoding_train[start:end,:].T
        #print(len(y_batch.T))
        # First Convolutional Layer
        X_im2col = im2col(X=X_batch, conv1=conv1, stride=1, pad=0)
        conv1_reshaped = conv1.reshape(conv1.shape[0], -1)
        X_conv = conv1_reshaped @ X_im2col
        X_conv = np.array(np.hsplit(X_conv, X_batch.shape[0])).reshape((X_batch.shape[0],   
                                                                conv1.shape[0], 124, 124))

        # Pass through ReLU
        X_relu = ReLU(X_conv)

        # Pass Through Max Pool
        X_maxpool = maxpool_multiple(X_relu, stride=2)

        # Second Convolutional Layer
        X_im2col_conv2 = im2col(X=X_maxpool, conv1=conv2, stride=1, pad=0)
        conv2_reshaped = conv2.reshape(conv2.shape[0], -1)
        X_conv2 = conv2_reshaped @ X_im2col_conv2
        X_conv2 = np.array(np.hsplit(X_conv2, X_maxpool.shape[0])).reshape((X_maxpool.shape[0], 
                                                                      conv2.shape[0], 58, 58))

        # Pass through ReLU
        X_relu2 = ReLU(X_conv2)

        # Pass Through Max Pool
        X_maxpool2 = maxpool_multiple(X_relu2, stride=2)

        # Get the indices of maxpool
        max_indices2 = maxpool_indices_multiple(X_relu2, stride=2, filter_height=2, filter_width=2)

        # Flatten the maxpool output
        input_shape2 = X_maxpool2.shape[0]
        num_channels2 = X_maxpool2.shape[1]
        input_width2 = X_maxpool2.shape[2]
        input_height2 = X_maxpool2.shape[3]
        X_maxpool_flatten2 = np.zeros((input_width2 * input_height2 * num_channels2, input_shape2))
        for image in range(input_shape2):
            X_maxpool_flatten2[:, image:image + 1] = X_maxpool2[image:image + 1, :, :,
                                                      :].reshape(-1, 1)

        # Getting into first fully connected layer
        fc1 = ReLU(W1 @ X_maxpool_flatten2 + B0)

        # Getting into second fully connected layer
        final_fc = softmax(W2 @ fc1 + B1)

        # Calculating Loss Through Backprop
        delta_2 = (final_fc - y_batch)
        delta_1 = np.multiply(W2.T @ delta_2, dReLU(W1 @ X_maxpool_flatten2 + B0))
        delta_0 = np.multiply(W1.T @ delta_1, 1.0)

        dW1 = delta_1 @ X_maxpool_flatten2.T
        dW2 = delta_2 @ fc1.T
        dB0 = np.sum(delta_1, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        dB1 = np.sum(delta_2, axis=1, keepdims=True)

        delta_maxpool2 = delta_0.reshape(X_maxpool2.shape)

        delta_conv2 = np.zeros(X_conv2.shape)
        for image in range(len(max_indices2)):
            indices = max_indices2[image]
            for p in indices:
                delta_conv2[image:image + 1, p[1], p[2], p[3]] = delta_maxpool2[image:image + 1,      
                                                                               p[5], p[6], p[7]]
        delta_conv2 = np.multiply(delta_conv2, dReLU(X_conv2))

        X_maxpool_im2col = im2col(X=X_maxpool, conv1=conv2, stride=1, pad=0)
        delta_conv2_reshape = error_layer_reshape(delta_conv2)
        conv2_delta = (delta_conv2_reshape @ X_maxpool_im2col.T).reshape(2, 2, 5, 5)
        
        # Berechnung des Fehlergradienten für den zweiten Convolutional Layer (conv2)
        d2 = np.multiply(W1.T @ delta_1, dReLU(X_maxpool_flatten2))
        d2_reshape = d2.reshape(X_maxpool2.shape)

        # Rückverfolgung durch den zweiten Convolutional Layer (conv2)
        delta_conv1 = np.zeros(X_conv.shape)
        for image in range(len(max_indices2)):
            indices = max_indices2[image]
            for p in indices:
                delta_conv1[image:image + 1, p[1], p[2], p[3]] = d2_reshape[image:image + 1, p[5],    
                                                                                   p[6], p[7]]
        delta_conv1 = np.multiply(delta_conv1, dReLU(X_conv))
        
        X_maxpool_im2col = im2col(X=X_maxpool, conv1=conv1, stride=1, pad=0)
        delta_conv1_reshape = error_layer_reshape(delta_conv1)
        conv1_delta = (delta_conv1_reshape @ X_maxpool_im2col.T).reshape(2, 2, 5, 5)
        # Jetzt haben Sie delta für den ersten Convolutional Layer (conv1)


        momentum_w1 = beta1 * momentum_w1 + (1 - beta1) * dW1
        momentum_w2 = beta1 * momentum_w2 + (1 - beta1) * dW2
        momentum_b0 = beta1 * momentum_b0 + (1 - beta1) * dB0
        momentum_b1 = beta1 * momentum_b1 + (1 - beta1) * dB1
        momentum_conv1 = beta1 * momentum_conv1 + (1 - beta1) * conv1_delta
        momentum_conv2 = beta1 * momentum_conv2 + (1 - beta1) * conv2_delta

        velocity_w1 = beta2 * velocity_w1 + (1 - beta2) * (momentum_w1 ** 2)
        velocity_w2 = beta2 * velocity_w2 + (1 - beta2) * (momentum_w2 ** 2)
        velocity_b0 = beta2 * velocity_b0 + (1 - beta2) * (momentum_b0 ** 2)
        velocity_b1 = beta2 * velocity_b1 + (1 - beta2) * (momentum_b1 ** 2)
        velocity_conv1 = beta2 * velocity_conv1 + (1 - beta2) * (conv1_delta ** 2)
        velocity_conv2 = beta2 * velocity_conv2 + (1 - beta2) * (conv2_delta ** 2)

        # Update Weights
        conv1 = conv1 - learning_rate * momentum_conv1 / np.sqrt(velocity_conv1 + 0.0000001)
        conv2 = conv2 - learning_rate * momentum_conv2 / np.sqrt(velocity_conv2 + 0.0000001)
        W1 = W1 - learning_rate * momentum_w1 / np.sqrt(velocity_w1 + 0.0000001)
        W2 = W2 - learning_rate * momentum_w2 / np.sqrt(velocity_w2 + 0.0000001)
        B0 = B0 - learning_rate * momentum_b0 / np.sqrt(velocity_b0 + 0.0000001)
        B1 = B1 - learning_rate * momentum_b1 / np.sqrt(velocity_b1 + 0.0000001)
```

I have tried to expand the CNN

I could not run the backpropagation through the CNN